# Force TOhtml to generate a HTML output rather than a HTML5 output in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: vimdiff

My python code opens a subprocess which in turn calls `vimdiff` and `:toHTML`.

Snippet added below:

```
subprocess.check_call(
            [
                "vimdiff",
                oldfileresultnameafterrename,
                build_xml_path,
                "-c",
                ":se nu | TOhtml | w! "+oldfileresultnameafterrename+".html | qa!"
            ]
```

In CentOS, it generates an HTML output and everything works as expected. Now I'm migrating to Ubuntu and the same command generates a HTML5 page.

Is there a way, I can generate a HTML page similar to the one generated in CentOS?

Comment: I suspect  both distribution to not use the same version of  Vim. Can you tell us what is the output of `:version` Vim command on both systems?

Comment: Hi, CentOS VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 and Ubuntu VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2

Answer (score 0):

The two Vims are probably two different versions, with two different versions of the `:TOhtml` script. Compare the output of `$ vim --version` in both environments to make sure.

Anyway, the version I currently use (9.0_v2 in Vim 9.0.1897) exposes the `:help g:html_use_css` option which, rather unintuitively, switches the rendered HTML to 4.01:

```
" option
:let g:html_use_css = 0

" output
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
[…]

" option (default value)
:let g:html_use_css = 1

" output
<!DOCTYPE html>
[…]
```

If I were you I would try to convince the maintainer of that script to refactor it a bit for clarity. Something like `g:html_use_html5` would be so much better.

Comment: CentOS  is running on Vim 7.4 and Ubuntu on 8.2, I upgraded it to version 9.0 and added let g:html_use_css = 0 in the Vimrc.
Now the HTML generated is missing the CSS, which was required to find the element using XPATH.

Comment: Well… it looks like you are left with playing with the options under `:help :tohtml` and/or opening an issue in Vim's issue tracker.